# Printing \G on shell using mysql client..?

Tags: mysql

It is really a a headache for me from some hours i am struggling on the problem.I have also asked it on [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411726/issue-in-printing-g-in-mysql/9411960#comment11895267_9411960) but not got any answer yet so i am asking here.Sorry for Not a good question.

I am Executing a Command on Linux shell.

```
mysql -uroot -proot -Bse "select Concat('SHOW CREATE TABLE ',TABLE_SCHEMA ,'.',TABLE_NAME,'\\G') from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA Not IN('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema');"
```

I want output as

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE sakila.category\G
SHOW CREATE TABLE sakila.city\G
SHOW CREATE TABLE sakila.country\G
SHOW CREATE TABLE sakila.customer\G
```

But I am getting as

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE sakila.categoryG
SHOW CREATE TABLE sakila.cityG
SHOW CREATE TABLE sakila.countryG
SHOW CREATE TABLE sakila.customerG
```

Why it is so..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has always been a real pain-in-the-neck for me.

- The mysql client seems to interpret the `\\G` as  `\G`
- The OS seems to take that output and interpret `\G` as `G`

Unfortunately, this is the sequence that always happens.

I use the [**sed**](http://www.sedtutorial.com/) command to get around this as follows:

```
mysql -uroot -proot -Bse "select Concat('SHOW CREATE TABLE ',TABLE_SCHEMA ,'.',TABLE_NAME,' G') from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA Not IN('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema');" | sed 's/ G$/\\G/g'
```

Notice that I replaced `\\G` with `G` (blank followed by `G`)

I have the sed command translate `G$` (which means the blank capital G at the end of of line) and convert it to `\G`. Notice that sed is doing this conversion with OS output and mysql output.

You no longer have to deal with that `\G` issue. Simply plan for a blank capital G to be transalted by sed to `\G`.

Comment: if we use -Bre (r stands for raw) instead of s then it works with \\\\G.